# Umbraco 4 FileService

Tags: umbraco

Ok as the name stated Umbraco 4 Fileservice, but I dont think FileService works on umbraco 4.

I have an Umbraco 4 project where I need to get all my templates, I need to extract their name, aliases, parent template and the content for personal use, but I dont know how to get all of them, in Umbraco 6 and 7 it was easy using FileService but I am on Umbraco 4.

I hope somebody here can help me to do this in Umbraco 4, because I really need to get all those templates, not only templates but also some items like macroscripts.

(please dont advise about creating packages I dont want to use that)

Thanks a lot

Comment: I believe uSync can export that for you (if you can find the old V4 version).

Comment: Thanks, I want my own version for some reason

Comment: "Some reason"? Excellent.

Comment: Example: I dont have ftp / server access to the live site (umbraco 4), so I dont want to install any packages that might break the site, so only solution is to insert some script on one of the master pages.

Another reason, I want to enhance my skills on manipulating the backend of umbraco 4 so I can use it later.

Too many reason so I will call it instead as "some reason"

Comment: If you need a sorting function you're also writing your own? :) uSync is one of the most popular packages for Umbraco now and it's doing awesome job with transfering content of sites between instances. You can also check Umbraco Courier which is a commercial package and it's also available for older Umbraco versions (it costs 99 EUR per domain): https://our.umbraco.org/projects/umbraco-pro/umbraco-courier-2/. If you want to do it in "hardcore way", go with pure SQL queries ;)

Comment: @MarcinZajkowski will you install uSync package in a live site where you dont have access on ftp/server if the site break? and suppose I have uSync on the site how can I get then those files inside uSync folder.

Comment: @RenanteAbril hmm it may be not so helpful and easy if you don't have access to files. But if you'll be stubborn, you can then create a package / DLL which will be just copying-pasting those JSON files between instances and you'll be able to IMPORT them in new / second instance. But still - with v4.x - Courier may be the better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't/won't use uSync, you'll need to write your own code to do it. The FileService was introduced in 6 I think, so it doesn't work in 4.

To get all of the templates in code, you would do something like this:

```
var templates = umbraco.cms.businesslogic.template.Template.GetAllAsList();

foreach (var item in templates)
{
    //template alias
    item.Alias;
    //parent id
    item.ParentId;
    //the path to the master file so you can get using system.io
    item.TemplateFilePath;
    //the name of the template
    item.Text;
}
```